# Img alt tag showing different value then entered

Tags: images, seo, customization

I have a WordPress website "https://drgadyabramson.com" I am optimizing the website for better ranking. But the problem is Yoast SEO showing me that "The images on this page do not have alt attributes containing the focus keyword." The thing is I have placed alt tag to each and every image used on that page.

[image: Alt tag inserted from the media library]

But when I check the source code then it shows different ALT tag that i have inserted in media library. Check below:

[image: Different ALT then inserted]

It looks like my website automatically fetch ALT from title. But It's not good for SEO.

Any of you please suggests me the solution? Do I need to change in the theme file? If yes then what it would be?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alt attribute in the media library does not add or update it on any of your pages where it's already been inserted in content.

When you add an image to content using the editor, it's added as an HTML `<img>` tag, including alt attribute. Once it's been added, it's just HTML, so making changes in the media library can't affect it.

To add alt text to your images you'll need to go into each page, select and edit the images there, and add the alt text that you want.

Comment: But there are no options to add alt tag by going to the text mode. because of my website use visual composer.

Comment: Then you'll need to take that up with the authors of Visual Composer.

Comment: Jacob do you know the code that works?

Comment: It's not a code issue. The problem is with your content. You need to edit your content to add the alt text. If you cannot do that then the problem is with Visual Composer, and you need to ask them for help.

Comment: No. It's not a problem with Visual Composer. I have several websites running on visual composer but those websites don't have this issue.

Comment: Mate, I don't know what you want me to tell you. You added images with visual composer. Those images aren't doing what you want. That's an issue with Visual Composer. Simple as that.

Comment: Checkout this source code:[plethora_teaserbox title="Dr. Gady Abramson" subtitle="Best Chiropractor In Kendall" boxed_styling="boxed" image="1175" media_colorset="transparent" text_colorset="transparent" button_style="btn-secondary" same_height="same_height_col"][/plethora_teaserbox]

Comment: Looks pretty obvious to me that the `title=""` is being used as the alt text. Have you tried changing that? Regardless, this is a 3rd-party shortcode and, like I said, if that shortcode isn't doing what you want, you need to take it up with the author. It's not a WordPress issue.

Comment: If I uninstall that third-party plugin then my entire site is going to crash that's for sure.

Comment: So don't uninstall it. I didn't tell you to anyway. But if something about it isn't working properly, then you will need to contact their support for help. 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the alt_text if you are pulling the image with custom code. I hope this might help you if you are just searching for the $alt text

`$alt_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);`

Edit 1:

If you are pulling the image through wordpress function then only you can see the alt tag also being pulled in the output.
`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), array('700', '600'), "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ) );  ?>`

If you have an image being called manually with the only URL, then you can add alt as the variable which possibly should pull alt detail as following:

`<img src="your method to call URL" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>`

Comment: Thanks but where do I add this code? functions.php?

Comment: Please check again for the edited section in Answer.